# It is possible to export a MySQL database without BLOB fields?

Tags: mysql, export

If I have a MySQL database with some tables where one have a BLOB column, It is possible to export the whole database excluding the BLOB fields? If not, could you suggest a solution to *work-around* it?

Comment: is the answer by Mahesh satisfying?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldbexport` utility does this, I have myself not tried though,
It has `--skip-blobs` which prevents exporting of `blob` data.
For more information refer this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbexport.html